# Where to look for redirect configurations in Wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect non-www URLs of our site (site A) to their www counterparts but I can't seem to do this. I know this can be done via the htaccess file and I've tried doing adjustments but to no avail. The current htaccess config is:

```
# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.website.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

We have a different Wordpress site (site B) that redirects non-www URLs to www URLs properly, including with-trailing-slash URLs to without-trailing-slash URLs. But when I checked its htaccess file, there seems to be no redirect configs present. Specifically, the codes present are:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

I have a feeling that in this case, the redirections may have been configured somewhere else and I am probably wrong to be looking at the htaccess file. Could I be correct? Where else should I look? We have a plugin that handles redirects (for site A) but it doesn't have any configs for non-www to redirect to www, or for with-trailing-slash to redirect to without-trailing-slash. So I don't think it's the plugin.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using rewrite plugins and htaccess rules tend to cause redirect loops. I would turn off the plugins and just use .htaccess rules if your going to do any.

Comment: everything works fine with the site that uses redirect plugins so there's no problem there. the prob I have is with that other site that doesn't use a redirect plugin. but like I said above, the plugin does not have any configs for redirecting non-www to www so I don't think it's the plugin

Answer (score 0):

For the site A you need to make `RewriteEngine on` before you write any rule in .htaccess file so your file should look like below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.website.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now for the case of Site B, WordPress has inbuilt feature, if you have installed your WordPress with `www` in domain then it will redirect all pages which are accessed without `www` in URL.

If you want override what has been stored in database then you can use below constants in your `wp-config.php` file

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.yourdomain.com');
```

Comment: Is this supposed to apply reverse (from www to non-www)? I'm referring to subdomains typed with www but which I'd like to redirect to non-www (currently not working).